# Is it true that anyone who is born, is a Shudra by default?

Tags: caste-system, shudra

I have heard that any one who is born is shudra by default.
How true is it?

Comment: No it’s not. Janmana Jayate is considered an interpolated verse. It doesn’t accurately reflect the caste system